# Looking for a solution to the web site searching problem

Tags: wordpress, search

I have a WordPress website. The website is running with a customized theme. I'm having a problem with my site. Searching for something on the web site only shows 10 results. I want to show everything. What should I do in this case? Can anyone tell me?

Comment: it's 10 showing because in the admin reading section you set only 10 posts. If you want to show all then need to change the code or you can increase the limit.

Comment: Can you tell me where to change the code or how to increase the search results?

Comment: Please add the code here which you tired

Answer (score 0):

You can change it from here easily.

[image]